# Use an entire array across multiple files Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Ok so here's my problem.  I got an array in my "main file" and I need to be able to use that array across other files.

```
var myArray = []
```

This array holds sockets connecting to my server, so it's constantly changing

```
function putsSocketsInArray () {
myArray.push(rawSockets) }
```

Now I wanna use that array for example, in another script to write to all the sockets in the array.

```
  'use strict'
//broadcast function

function talkAll (myArray, message, sender) {
    myArray.forEach(function (connection) {
        //don't want to send it to sender
        if (connection === sender) return;
    connection.write(`${message} \n`);
    });

}

module.exports = talkAll
```

This works as long as the function talkAll is same "main.js" file.

(code in main.js) (It's a telnet server)

```
telnetSocket.on('data', function (data) {

talkAll(myArray, telnetSocket.name + ">" + data, telnetSocket);
});
```

Well I need to seperate it out into a module, but when I do my second.js file can't use the myArray at all.  It will error out that the array is not defined.  Yet when I make any attempt to define it in the second.js or even try to build a function to fetch that array. the Array becomes blank.

The answer provided by jcaron below worked for me.  Also kids, make sure you're not editing the wrong script for 10 minutes.

Comment: You need to export it.

Comment: Every time I export the array, my .forEach errors out that it's not a function

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: what's the syntax for exporting an array? module.exports = myArray?

Comment: I'm also importing it into my second.js file using const myArray =require('./main.js')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to passing the array from main.js to individual modules is to make the array itself a module that gets required by any module that needs it.

The thing that makes this work is to realise that node modules are not merely cached but are actually proper [singletons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). That means that each time a module gets imported the same object gets imported.

The implementation is simplicity itself:

In `shared-array.js`:

```
var sharedArray = [];
module.exports = sharedArray;
```

In any file that create sockets:

```
var sharedArray = require('./path/to/shared-array');
// ...
sharedArray.push(socketObject);
```

In any file that need to use those sockets:

```
var sharedArray = require('./path/to/shared-array');
// ...
var socket = sharedArray[socketIndex];
```

Comment: Wow that worked like a charm! Thanks that's a really nifty way to do that!

Answer (score 0):

If `myArray` is defined in your main file, which `require`s another file, you need to pass your array to functions inside your second file.

```
var myArray = [];

var myModule = require('mymodule');
...
myModule.talkAll(myArray,message,sender);
```

Of course, you need to add that argument to your talkAll function.

There are lots of alternatives depending on how exactly you implemented your module. You could also have a function to set a local variable to that array.

Comment: I'm still getting an issue with connections.forEach when I try to seperate that array in my second file.  TypeError: connections.forEach is not a function

Comment: I'm updated, let me know if you need more, my main.js is over 70's lines.  But my script is shutting down specifically in the talkAll.js file when it attempts to myArray.forEach.    Stating that myArray.forEach is not a function

Comment: Your updated code in your question does not do anything like what I'm suggesting in this answer. Don't include your main file in your module, pass your array as an argument to the function inside your module.

Comment: You mean as in function broadcast(myArray, message, sender)?

Comment: same issue "connections.forEach is not a function"  I appreciate the help by the way, but I think I've made some terrible mistake and will need to figure something else out.

Comment: Your new edit makes more sense, but please show how you call the function `talkAll` (and remove the `const myArray = require('./server1')`)

Comment: Done.  Keep in mine it's a telnet server and the myArray is pushed a new item every time a user connects and splices it off everytime a user disconnects.

Comment: You need to add the array as the first argument in your call to the function as well...

Comment: That was it!  Oh my God dude I'd kiss you in person if I could.  Thank you so much.